# how to disable hyperlink and copy/paste menu on iOS and webviewdidfinishload not called

Tags: ios, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm trying to disable hyperlink and copy/paste menu on iOS UIwebview
so I googled and there were a lot of answers.
then I encountered with another problem 'webviewdidfinishload not called'
so I add my code to ask your help. (Iam sure I properly connected IBOutlet)

In additional, I still not get the idea of putting mainWebView.delegate = self instead of self.mainWebView.delegate = self 
could anyone explain the difference?
so iam not sure my other functions like 
    [[[mainWebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:YES]
    [[[mainWebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollsToTop:NO]
    mainWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES
these are working or not.

it should be working on ios5 to ios6.1
thank you

in .h file

```
@interface HRViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    UIWebView *mainWebView;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *mainWebView;

@end
```

---

in .m file

```
@interface HRViewController ()

@end

@implementation HRViewController

@synthesize mainWebView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self startWebView];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)startWebView
{
    mainWebView.delegate = self;

    [[[mainWebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [[[mainWebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollsToTop:NO]; 
    mainWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

    mainWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    mainWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.mainWebView];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:/" @"http://www.mysite.com" "/];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [mainWebView loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)WebView {
    NSLog(@"finish");

    [WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none';"];
    [WebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)mainWebView {
    NSLog(@"start");
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error for WEBVIEW: %@", [error description]);
}
```

EDIED
I used below codes but still doesnt work...
none of these doesnt work!!!!!

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"canPerformAction: %@",NSStringFromSelector(action));
    if (action == @selector(copy:) ||
        action == @selector(paste:)||
        action == @selector(cut:)) {
        return NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

and this

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    if (menuController) {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

even this
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        mainWebView.delegate = self;
    }

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"finish");
    // Disable user selection
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none';"];
    // Disable callout
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"];
}
```

also this
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [self longPress:self.mainWebView];
    }

```
- (void)longPress:(UIView *)webView {
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress)];

    longPress.allowableMovement=100;
    longPress.minimumPressDuration=0.3;
    longPress.delaysTouchesBegan=YES;
    longPress.cancelsTouchesInView=YES; 
    [webView addGestureRecognizer:longPress]; 
}

// I just need this for the selector in the gesture recognizer.
- (void)handleLongPress {

}
```

Please help me.. it drives me crazy for a week now..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**To hide the copy/paste menu:**

Override the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method to return `NO` for actions that you don't want to allow:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;

    if (action == @selector(select:))   
        return NO;

    if (action == @selector(selectAll:))   
        return NO;

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Another way:

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    if (menuController) {
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Also check [This link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**To disable hyperlinks:**

You can get the answer for this question from [this site](http://www.macoscoders.com/tag/webkittouchcallout/).

**Regarding the `UIWebView`:**

If you use ARC then write only,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *mainWebView;
```

No need to `@synthesize` the property, Other wise,

```
@interface HRViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    UIWebView *mainWebView;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *mainWebView;

@end

// .m file

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mainWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    mainWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    mainWebView.delegate = self;

    [[[mainWebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [[[mainWebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollsToTop:NO];
    mainWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:self.mainWebView];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [mainWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

This might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it still doesnt work for me. I tried them all but nothing worked. I even disabled longpressgesture but doesnt work. Adding javascript to CSS didnt work either.. I dont know the problem but it drives me crazy.. but one progress is now webViewDidFinishLoad is called(nslog comfirmed.) addtional help needed